# Notifydatasetchanged not working in Recycler view Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am trying create home view like tiktok.There is a like button on top of the video.Onclick to  change the status in arraylist and notify the adapter. adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() not working it seems.there must be some mistake which I could not find it.please help me out.

Thank you....!

Adapter :

```
public class Home_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Home_Adapter.CustomViewHolder > {

public Context context;
private Home_Adapter.OnItemClickListener listener;
private ArrayList<Home_Get_Set> dataList;



// meker the onitemclick listener interface and this interface is implemented in Chatinbox activity
// for to do action when user click on item
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int positon,Home_Get_Set item, View view);
}



public Home_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Home_Get_Set> dataList, Home_Adapter.OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dataList = dataList;
    this.listener = listener;

}

public void setDataList(final int position, final Home_Get_Set home_get_set,String action){
    dataList.remove(position);
    home_get_set.liked=action;
    dataList.add(position,home_get_set);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public Home_Adapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewtype) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_home_layout,null);
    view.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    return new CustomViewHolder(view);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
   return dataList.size();
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final Home_Adapter.CustomViewHolder holder, final int i) {
    final Home_Get_Set item= dataList.get(i);
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

    try {

    holder.bind(i,item,listener);

    holder.username.setText(item.username);


        if((item.sound_name==null || item.sound_name.equals("") || item.sound_name.equals("null"))){
            holder.sound_name.setText("original sound - "+item.first_name+" "+item.last_name);
        }else {
            holder.sound_name.setText(item.sound_name);
        }
       holder.sound_name.setSelected(true);


    holder.desc_txt.setText(item.video_description);

    Picasso.get().
            load(item.profile_pic)
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_image_placeholder))
            .resize(100,100).into(holder.user_pic);



        if((item.sound_name==null || item.sound_name.equals(""))
                || item.sound_name.equals("null")){

            item.sound_pic=item.profile_pic;

        }
        else if(item.sound_pic.equals(""))
            item.sound_pic="Null";
        Picasso.get().
            load(item.sound_pic).centerCrop()
            .placeholder(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_round_music))
            .resize(100,100).into(holder.sound_image);


        Log.d("liked",""+item.liked);
    if(item.liked.equals("1")){

        holder.like_image.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_like_fill));
    }
   else {
        holder.like_image.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_like));
    }


    holder.like_txt.setText(Functions.GetSuffix(item.like_count));
    holder.comment_txt.setText(Functions.GetSuffix(item.video_comment_count));


        if(item.verified!=null && item.verified.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            holder.varified_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            holder.varified_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
  }



class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView username,desc_txt,sound_name;
    ImageView user_pic,sound_image,varified_btn;

    LinearLayout like_layout,comment_layout,shared_layout,sound_image_layout;
    ImageView like_image,comment_image;
    TextView like_txt,comment_txt;


    public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);


        username=view.findViewById(R.id.username);
        user_pic=view.findViewById(R.id.user_pic);
        sound_name=view.findViewById(R.id.sound_name);
        sound_image=view.findViewById(R.id.sound_image);
        varified_btn=view.findViewById(R.id.varified_btn);

        like_layout=view.findViewById(R.id.like_layout);
        like_image=view.findViewById(R.id.like_image);
        like_txt=view.findViewById(R.id.like_txt);


        desc_txt=view.findViewById(R.id.desc_txt);

        comment_layout=view.findViewById(R.id.comment_layout);
        comment_image=view.findViewById(R.id.comment_image);
        comment_txt=view.findViewById(R.id.comment_txt);


        sound_image_layout=view.findViewById(R.id.sound_image_layout);
        shared_layout=view.findViewById(R.id.shared_layout);
    }

    public void bind(final int postion,final Home_Get_Set item, final 
  Home_Adapter.OnItemClickListener listener) {

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onItemClick(postion,item,v);
            }
        });


        user_pic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                listener.onItemClick(postion,item,v);
            }
        });

        username.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                listener.onItemClick(postion,item,v);
            }
        });


        like_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                listener.onItemClick(postion,item,v);
            }
        });


        comment_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                listener.onItemClick(postion,item,v);
            }
        });

        shared_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                listener.onItemClick(postion,item,v);
            }
        });

        sound_image_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onItemClick(postion,item,v);
            }
        });


    }


}


}
```

Activity :

```
  recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recylerview);
    layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

  // this is the scroll listener of recycler view which will tell the current item number
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        }
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            //here we find the current item number
            final int scrollOffset = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset();
            final int height = recyclerView.getHeight();
            int page_no=scrollOffset / height;

            if(page_no!=currentPage ){
                currentPage=page_no;

                Release_Privious_Player();
                Set_Player(currentPage);

            }
        }
      });


Home_Adapter adapter;
   public void Set_Adapter(){

     adapter=new Home_Adapter(context, data_list, new Home_Adapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int postion, final Home_Get_Set item, View view) {

            switch(view.getId()) {

                case R.id.user_pic:
                    onPause();
                    OpenProfile(item,false);
                    break;

                case R.id.username:
                    onPause();
                    OpenProfile(item,false);
                    break;

                case R.id.like_layout:
                    if(Variables.sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Variables.islogin,false)) {
                    Like_Video(postion, item);
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Please Login.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;

                case R.id.comment_layout:
                    OpenComment(item);
                    break;

             
              
            }

        }
    });

    adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
  public void Like_Video(final int position, final Home_Get_Set home_get_set){
    String action=home_get_set.liked;
     Log.d("liked",""+home_get_set.liked);
    Log.d("liked",""+home_get_set.video_description);
    Log.d("liked",""+home_get_set.username);
    if(action.equals("1")){
        action="0";
        home_get_set.like_count=""+(Integer.parseInt(home_get_set.like_count) -1);
    }else {
        action="1";
        home_get_set.like_count=""+(Integer.parseInt(home_get_set.like_count) +1);
    }


   data_list.remove(position);
    home_get_set.liked=action;
   data_list.add(position,home_get_set);
    // adapter.setDataList(position,home_get_set,action);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    Log.d("liked","notifyed");
}
```

Comment: Also add `notifyItemChanged(position);`

Comment: Still same not updating